# How to silently uninstall Java in Windows in a repeatable manner?

Tags: java

How can I uninstall Java on Windows in a repeatable manner. I install Java with:

```
jdk-7u17-windows-x64-1.0.exe /s INSTALLDIR="C:\jdk1.7.0_17"
```

but when I try to uninstall Java with

```
jdk-7u17-windows-x64-1.0.exe /s /x INSTALLDIR="C:\jdk1.7.0_17"
```

just brings up an error dialog box every time showing the Java command line options

Comment: I tend to just delete it from the install location (when upgrading) and replace my JAVA_HOME var. My PATH is usually set up to point to my `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`, not the install dir directly.

Comment: Yes, that does work, but I need to use the JDK official uninstaller for contractual reasons where I work

Comment: See this ->http://superuser.com/questions/257788/how-to-uninstall-java-se-from-the-command-line